# How can i use multiple react-color picker in single component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I am using react-color for color pick and theming, I am not able to use multiple color picker in single react component, when I click on one color picker, it populates others as well.

I don't know why i am not able to add code here, for the ref. there is screenshot, could you please see now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjeuG.png)

Comment: Hello Rahul and welcome to stackoverflow ! 
can you provide your application code where the logic is ? without the code we simply cannot help you to solve your current problem

Comment: The easiest option is to use a snippet (There's an icon for it in the question editor), but here's a meta question that should help if you're struggling to include the code as text: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Thanks @MaieonBrix i am new bee at asking questions, i have added a screenshot here could you plz check.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, it's much better, but it will be perfect for this platform if you could copy paste your whole component code in here (dont forget to remove any sensitive data such as api keys, logins, etc)